# iOS second touch never triggers UIControlEventTouchUpInside

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hey let's say I have 2 buttons and set the selectors like this:

```
 button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(actionPick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
 button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(actionUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(actionPick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
 button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(actionUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Both are working perfectly fine except that if I do the following, `actionUp:` doesn't get called.

```
TouchDown button1 //works
TouchDown button2 //works
Touch  Up button2 //works
Touch  Up button1 //not called
```

So I

- hit the first button (leave my finger on it)
- hit the second one
- release the second
- release the first button

Any idea on how to fix this? Why does the `actionUp:` appears to be consumed before I even lift the finger?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this behavior but I couldn't. My two buttons work as expected:

Comment: TouchDown button1 -> TouchDown button2 -> TouchUp button2 -> TouchUp button 1

Comment: Have you tried different version of iOS?  Do they behave the same way?

Comment: I could not reproduce this bug on an iPhone 6 running 9.1beta.

Comment: I've tried this connecting the actions directly from the storyboard and it seems to work as expected:

Comment: Works fine for me. Tested on iOS7 and iOS9.

Answer (score 1):

Check multipleTouchEnabled property of your UIView. It default value is NO

Answer (score 0):

I've made a demo project to study the events of buttons in iOS.
My Demo seems to work fine in all scenarios, I could not add enough explanations here due to time limit so, Here's the link to the git Repo.... 
[click Here](https://github.com/bhaumikdesai91/TouchEventsDemOApp.git)

See what you can find... 
Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it on iPhone 5s + iPhone 6 + iPhone 6 Plus with iOS 7.1 + iOS 8.0 and iOS 9.0.2 and works fine. Well, if it happens always, your event target hierarchy is wrong or broken in someway. Try to remove all targets before add like that;

```
[button1 removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];

[button2 removeTarget:nil  action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
```